# Qt - How to do superscripts and subscripts in a QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, superscript, subscript

I need to have the ability to use superscripts asnd subscripts in a QLineEdit in Qt 4.6. I know how to do superscripts and subscripts in a QTextEdit as seen below but I can't figure out how to do them in QLineEdit because the class doesn't contain a mergeCurrentCharFormat() function like QTextEdit does. Please help. Thanks

```
void MainWindow::superscriptFormat()
{
   QTextCharFormat format;
   format.setVerticalAlignment(QTextCharFormat::AlignSuperScript);
   if(ui->txtEdit->hasFocus())
      ui->txtEdit->mergeCurrentCharFormat(format);
}
```

Comment: There are some tips at the end of this page on how to make a single line QTextEdit: http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2005-04/thread00302-0.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was able to try this out in the builder. However, when I make it that small it shows an up and down arrow on the right side of the QTextEdit which is not desirable but if I cannot get superscripts or subscripts in a QLineEdit then I guess this will have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QLineEdit` wasn't really made for this type of thing, as it was designed for simple text entry.  You have a few options, however.  The simplest one is to do as Hostile Fork suggested and use a `QTextEdit`, and add a style override to not show the scroll bar (which I assume would remove the arrows).  The more complex one would be to either inherit `QLineEdit` and do your own drawing, or to make your own widget completely that appears similar to the `QLineEdit`s do.

Comment: Thanks! I had found the word wrap part but was looking for something about the scroll bars and didn't see anything. I just double checked and found it. Now it looks great! Thanks!